# JSPDF : Genearte pdf from object of array and display like Lables

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I want to generate PDF from object of array and display like this which I have attached in image.[image: PDF data in Lable view] .how I can achieve this while my output is in row wise.

```
  htmlStr += '<table id="customers" class="table-wide">';
htmlStr += '<thead ></thead>';
htmlStr += '<tbody ></tbodyid>';
htmlStr += '</table>';
this.html = $(htmlStr);
```

Comment: You explore github ?

Comment: Yes they are diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to do it on your own. jsPDF-Autotable is not good option for this scenario. Following is something like a scratch it's not a perfect solution. Please work on it further.

Actually we are going to create grid cards until the page width and height.

If height reaches, add new page `doc.addPage()`.

If width reaches, add new row.

```js
    var data = [{
      "Name": "Ronan",
      "Email": "sodales.elit@eratSed.co.uk",
      "Company": "Malesuada Malesuada Ltd"
    }, {
      "Name": "Calvin",
      "Email": "amet.nulla@Vestibulumante.ca",
      "Company": "Donec Egestas Foundation"
    }, {
      "Name": "Kane",
      "Email": "Duis.mi@consectetueradipiscingelit.net",
      "Company": "Arcu Institute"
    }, {
      "Name": "Kasper",
      "Email": "magna.Phasellus.dolor@velconvallisin.co.uk",
      "Company": "Tempor LLP"
    }];
    
    
  

     var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
//Dimension of A4 in pts: 595 × 842

var pageWidth = 595;
var pageHeight = 842;

var pageMargin = 20;

pageWidth -= pageMargin * 2;
pageHeight -= pageMargin * 2;

var cellPadding = 10;
var cellWidth = 180;
var cellHeight = 70;
var lineHeight = 20;

var startX = pageMargin;
var startY = pageMargin;


doc.setFontSize(12);

var page = 1;

function createCard(item) {

  //cell projection
  var requiredWidth = startX + cellWidth + (cellPadding * 2);

  var requiredHeight = startY + cellHeight + (cellPadding * 2);



  if (requiredWidth <= pageWidth) {

    textWriter(item, startX + cellPadding, startY + cellPadding);

    startX = requiredWidth;
    //  startY += cellHeight + cellPadding;

  } else {


    if (requiredHeight > pageHeight) {
      doc.addPage();
      page++;
      doc.setPage(page);

      startY = pageMargin;
    } else {
      startY = requiredHeight;
    }

    startX = pageMargin;


    textWriter(item, startX + cellPadding, startY + cellPadding);

    startX = startX + cellWidth + (cellPadding * 2);
  }

}

function textWriter(item, xAxis, yAxis) {
  doc.text(item.Name, xAxis, yAxis);
  doc.text(item.Email, xAxis, yAxis + lineHeight);
  doc.text(item.Company, xAxis, yAxis + (lineHeight * 2));
}


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  createCard(data[i]);
}

doc.save('grid.pdf');
```

For reference https://jsfiddle.net/Purushoth/jodfkz59/

Comment: I am getting data from database in a table form and will use a for loop on it. I saw jsfiddle. I think I can fix that extended cut data by extending width of page

Comment: You can get data from html table too.

 As I said, it's not a perfect solution just a scratch. But it can give you a starting point. BTW i'm drowsy now. Please work on it.

Comment: I have tackel all design things but new page is not generating after page1 is full.  I tested some tricks but not working

Comment: once you reached the end of the current page. Have you tried to add new page `doc.addPage();` and set the page to current page. Like `doc.setPage(1);` then continue with the labels.

Is that what you have tried? What is the issue?

Comment: yes I tried            if (y >= pageHeight)  function but  not working. can you give last favor by doing it in fiddle ? please I am stuck on it

Comment: I will update the fiddle soon, I am at work now. Check the logics by yourself and try to find the flaw @tousifNoor

Comment: It's doable please be patient. Let me try to update the fiddle after work hours.

Comment: yes brother but I dont have command on this . Just doing a module. I tried 3,4 methods but they are making new page on every new entity.

Comment: I have somehow same issue. You got solved ? @tousif Noor

Comment: @Purushoth brother you free now ?

Comment: Updated the answer to add new page if the content exceeds.