# JSPDF : Showing Html tables data in Pdf in shape of Horizontal groups

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I want to generate PDF from Tables and display like this which I have attached in image.[image: PDF data in Lable view] .how I can achieve this while my output is in row wise.

```
  <table id="customers" class="table-wide">;
<thead ></thead>;
<tbody ></tbodyid>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSPDF : Genearte pdf from object of array and display like Lables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900822/jspdf-genearte-pdf-from-object-of-array-and-display-like-lables)

Comment: @Purushoth yes I did post . Because not getting answer . Can you help please ?

Comment: Please be patient. SO works because of contributors like you and me. Please be patient until people find time and answer the question. Until do research the jsPDF or AutoTable source code. You may find your way too :) Adding more redundant question will not help.